# `geometry` strangely affect the behavior of `ragged2e`

Tags: geometry, ragged2e

Look at this example:

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scheme=plain]{ctex}
\ctexset{linestretch=0pt}
\xeCJKsetup{CJKglue={},CJKecglue={},RubberPunctSkip=false,CheckSingle}

% \usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \raggedright%
  \emergencystretch=3em%
  \hbadness=10000%
}
\usepackage{zhlipsum}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily\zhlipsum
\end{document}
```

The last line of each paragraph is not properly aligned. For example, at the end of the first paragraph (characters should be vertically aligned):

[image]

However, if I comment the line `\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}`, then this problem disappear.

Strangely, if I uncomment `\usepackage{geometry}`, then one get the same result whether with or without `ragged2e` package.

Why `geometry` package can affect the behavior of `ragged2e`? Is this some kind of bug of `ragged2e`?

Comment: not related but you should not have the `%` here `\hbadness=10000%` otherwise tex will read ahead somewhat strangely looking for the end of the number

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought it is a good idea to add `%` at the end of each line so as to avoid extra space in the document. Would this cause unexpected error?

Comment: You need to add % if the end of line would cause a space but there it terminates the number and would not add a space so adding `%` stops the number terminating. But could you add an image showing the problem, perhaps with an arrow drawn on it? I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwdHK.png) from the document as posted but I do not see what is wrong (but I can not read this at all so it is hard for me to tell)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle For the sake of my internet connection I can only upload but not see the pictures. I've edited my question to add a picture showing the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry I do see it (reading this is clearly hard for me!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the standard `\raggedright` and `ragged2e` package `\RaggedRight` is that the `ragged2e` version is less ragged, it only adds a finite amount of stretch at the right hand side, This stops some lines being very short, the text is then allowed to stretch white space or if necessary hyphenate words to achieve line lengths which are allowed to vary in length but not be really short.

Usually this works well for Latin script but it does not work well here. The font setup is allowing a small amount of stretch between each character: a typical line looks like (via `\showoutput`)

```
...\hbox(8.08+1.90999)x345.0, glue set 0.48865
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
....\TU/FandolFang-Regular(0)/m/n/10 水
....\glue 0.0 plus 0.15152
....\TU/FandolFang-Regular(0)/m/n/10 厂
....\glue 0.0 plus 0.15152
....\TU/FandolFang-Regular(0)/m/n/10 共
....\glue 0.0 plus 0.15152
```

as all the characters are the same width, the only line where you see a different stretch is on the last line.

With `\raggedright` there is infinite (`fil`) stretch added to `\rightskip` so this inter-character stretch is never used. However with `\RaggedRight`, `\rightskip` has a finite stretch amount, so the difference between the total width of the characters and the specified `\textwidth` is shared between all the glue with finite stretch, so the inter-character spacing is stretched. The amount of stretching in each line is the same except for the last line where the infinite `\parfillskip` stretch means that there is no inter-character stretching, and you see the bad alignment.

`geometry` only accidentally fixes this as in this example the text width is then closer to an exact multiple of the characters.

As far as I can see, any fix for this would essentially be to undo the effect of `ragged2e` so the simplest way is not to use the `newcommands` option so that `\raggedright` retains its original meaning and you need `\RaggedRight` to get the `ragged2e` version.

I should say that this is based on first principles from looking at the tex box output log. It may be that the ctex packages have a specific fix for this. If someone knowledgable posts an answer I'd be happy to delete this,